# Figure alignment using sub caption

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subcaption

I'm trying to align some figures using the **subcaption** package.

My current code is that:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \subcaptionbox{}
            {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_a}} \hspace{.5em}
        {\includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{figs/legend} phantomsubcaption}
        \subcaptionbox{}
            {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_b}} \hfill
        \subcaptionbox{}
            {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_c}} 
        \caption{}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

However, I would like the first image to be left alined. I tried to use this:

```
\usepackage[export]{adjust box}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \subcaptionbox{}
        {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth, left]{figs/Fig_a}} \hspace{.5em}
    {\includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{figs/legend} phantomsubcaption}
    \subcaptionbox{}
        {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_b}} \hfill
    \subcaptionbox{}
        {\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_c}} 
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
```

With no success:

[image]

Also, the image with the **\phantomsubcaption** doesn't have the same heigh as Figure (a) and I would like it to be center vertically aligned, and not bottom or top, i.e., aligned with the center of Figure (a). Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: With your MWE I cannot reproduce alignment of your image. They are left aligned. About height of image is without them anything difficult to say. If they have different height ans you like to show all with the same height, you can say \includegraphicx[height=<desired height>]{...}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want? Just place the narrow figure in the first `\subcaptionbox`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_a}%
  \hspace{0.04\columnwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{figs/legend}}\hspace*{\fill}

\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_b}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_c}}

\caption{Some caption or this wouldn't make much sense}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want that (a) is centered with respect to the wide image, you can insert the narrow image in a zero width box:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\centering
\subcaptionbox{}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_a}%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \hspace{0.04\columnwidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{figs/legend}%
  }%
}\hspace*{\fill}

\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_b}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_c}} 

\caption{Some caption or this wouldn't make much sense}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want left aligned subcaptions, tell so to `caption`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\captionsetup[subfigure]{singlelinecheck=false}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_a}%
    \hspace{0.04\columnwidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\columnwidth]{figs/legend}%
}\hspace*{\fill}

\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_b}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.48\columnwidth]{figs/Fig_c}} 

\caption{Some caption or this wouldn't make much sense}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `\captionsetup[subfigure]{singlelinecheck=false}` can also go in the preamble, so it will affect all subcaptions.

[image]