# Shows figures on the right side

Tags: graphics, floats, pdftex, subcaption

I added figures to my latex file and for some reason, it shows them on the right side instead of in the center. How can I fix it?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{A Constant Rectangle\label{fig:2a}}[.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{rectangle_graph.png}}
\hspace{1em}
\vspace{0.3em}
\subcaptionbox{A Moving Square\label{fig:2b}}[.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{moving_block_graph.png}}
\vspace{0.3em}
\subcaptionbox{Green Lines\label{fig:2c}}[.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{green_lines_graph.png}}\hspace{1em}
\subcaptionbox{Diagonals\label{fig:2d}}[.4\linewidth]{\includegraphics[width=1.6in]{diagonals_graph.png}}
\caption{caption.}
\label{figure2}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. -- Does [Figure alignment using sub caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204684/124842) help?

Comment: Do you want to maybe use `\begin{figure*}` and `\end{figure*}`? Note the asterisk.

Comment: If I add * it spreads on both columns.

Comment: What I can see from your picture is that the images have a white border on their left, which can be cured by trimming them (see the `trim` option); moreover, `1.6in` is probably larger than `0.4\linewidth`. You can test whether my guess on the white border is right by trying `\fbox{\includegraphics{rectangle_graph.png}}` and seeing what TeX thinks about the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use absolute values for the width of the images! 3.2in for two images is wider than the column width!

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{A Constant Rectangle\label{fig:2a}}[.45\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{rectangle_graph.png}}
\quad
\subcaptionbox{A Moving Square\label{fig:2b}}[.45\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{moving_block_graph.png}}

\subcaptionbox{Green Lines\label{fig:2c}}[.45\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{green_lines_graph.png}}
\quad
\subcaptionbox{Diagonals\label{fig:2d}}[.45\linewidth]{%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{diagonals_graph.png}}

\caption{caption.}
\label{figure2}
\end{figure}
```

[image]